# Find devices informations (/dev path, ...) and debug usb devices in CLI

Tags: terminal, command-line, usb, unix

I recently moved from Linux to Mac OS, and I'm quite a bit lost in some situations.

I'm looking for the /dev name of my USB device (which is listed in the system_profiler SPUSBDataType).

On Linux I used to use dmesg or lsusb to find information about my devices.
The Mac OS *dmesg* command is just useless, and the syslog (even in debug mode) does not say anything about the plugged USB devices.

- Is there any way to monitor in real time (like dmesg -w with Linux) the plugged devices on Mac ?

I found the *system_profiler SPUSBDataType*, but this command does not help me to find the /dev id of my device.

- Is there an easy way to find the /dev name of (plugged) with Mac ?

The only way I found for now is to do one *ls /dev* before the device plug-in and one after, and diff them...

- And finally if I have to debug an USB device like "why it is not recognized on the system ? where is the problem ? how can I fix it ?" what are the commands I dispose of ?

On Linux I used to use dmesg/lsusb/lspci/syslog...

Comment: You're not alone in feeling lost - I remember coming to OS X from Solaris and to a lesser extent Linux.  Some of the answers to this [question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058134/) might help.