# Addressing a serial connection on Catalina (Pro unlike Air)

Tags: usb

I am trying to establish a connection to a serial device from a MacBook Pro, and it’s not behaving like my MacBook Air. Both machines are running Catalina 10.15.5. When the serial device is plugged into the Air, it shows up as /dev/tty.usbserial-33B78, and then I just pass that address to my command-line program and everything works fine.

However, when I plug the same device into the Pro (via an Apple-built USB-C Digital AV Multiport adaptor) no entries appear of the form of `/dev/*usb*`. Something else does happen, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

When I run `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`
(on the Pro) both before and after inserting the adaptor and serial device,
there are many extra lines of output:

```
<         USB3.1 Hub:
< 
<           Product ID: 0x1018
<           Vendor ID: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
<           Version: 40.09
<           Serial Number: DLC9316035EKD5667
<           Speed: Up to 5 Gb/s
<           Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
<           Location ID: 0x00100000 / 1
<           Current Available (mA): 900
<           Current Required (mA): 0
<           Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
< 
38,76d24
<         USB2.0 Hub:
< 
<           Product ID: 0x1017
<           Vendor ID: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
<           Version: 40.09
<           Serial Number: DLC9316035EKD5667
<           Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
<           Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
<           Location ID: 0x14100000 / 1
<           Current Available (mA): 500
<           Current Required (mA): 0
<           Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
< 
<             NGT-1:
< 
<               Product ID: 0xd9aa
<               Vendor ID: 0x0403  (Future Technology Devices International Limited)
<               Version: 6.00
<               Serial Number: 33B78
<               Speed: Up to 12 Mb/s
<               Manufacturer: Actisense
<               Location ID: 0x14110000 / 3
<               Current Available (mA): 500
<               Current Required (mA): 100
<               Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
< 
<             USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter:
< 
<               Product ID: 0x1463
<               Vendor ID: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
<               Version: 40.09
<               Serial Number: DLC9316035EKD5667
<               Speed: Up to 12 Mb/s
<               Manufacturer: Apple Inc
<               Location ID: 0x14120000 / 2
<               Current Available (mA): 500
<               Current Required (mA): 100
<               Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
<
```

In those lines, the adaptor is clearly revealed, as is the serial device known as “NGT-1”.
The hardware knows it’s there. The OS knows it’s there. The OS can even read the device’s serial number (33B78). But how do I access it?

I recorded the output from “ls -l /dev” both before and after plugging in the serial device. The diff of those files is this:

```
MacBook-Pro:Pro me$ diff llwithout.txt llwithDevice.txt 
7,9c7,9
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           33,  54 19 Aug 12:14 autofs_homedirmounter
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           32,  54 19 Aug 12:14 autofs_notrigger
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           31, 0x000009ca 19 Aug 12:14 autofs_nowait
---
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           33,  60 19 Aug 12:14 autofs_homedirmounter
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           32,  60 19 Aug 12:14 autofs_notrigger
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           31, 0x000009da 19 Aug 12:14 autofs_nowait
281c281
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           24,   1 19 Aug 12:13 dtrace
---
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           24,   7 19 Aug 12:13 dtrace
286,288c286,288
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           20,  13 20 Aug 12:10 io8log
< cr--r--r--  1 root  wheel           20,  14 19 Aug 12:13 io8logmt
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           20,  15 20 Aug 12:32 io8logtemp
---
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           20,  15 20 Aug 12:10 io8log
> cr--r--r--  1 root  wheel           20,   9 19 Aug 12:13 io8logmt
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel           20,  13 20 Aug 12:34 io8logtemp
293c293
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            3,   2 20 Aug 12:33 null
---
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel            3,   2 20 Aug 12:36 null
299c299
< crw-rw-rw-  1 root  tty             15,   1 20 Aug 12:33 ptmx
---
> crw-rw-rw-  1 root  tty             15,   1 20 Aug 12:36 ptmx
498c498
< crw--w----  1 me    tty             16,   0 20 Aug 12:33 ttys000
---
> crw--w----  1 me    tty             16,   0 20 Aug 12:36 ttys000
```

I don’t know what to make of it.

What address do I give to my serial device reader?

Why does the Pro behave differently from the Air?

I have read these threads:
[How to open a serial connection on High Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/305605/how-to-open-a-serial-connection-on-high-sierra)
and
[Cannot find serial device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368381/cannot-find-serial-device/368399#368399)
and
[Find devices informations (/dev path, ...) and debug usb devices in CLI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280716/find-devices-informations-dev-path-and-debug-usb-devices-in-cli) but they don’t go far enough to answer this. Perhaps they pertain to an earlier OS, or perhaps they don’t carry over to the use of the adaptor, or perhaps it’s got something to do with the T2 bus (as an Apple genius suggested), which the Pro has but the Air doesn’t.

Comment: I downloaded  [Serial App](https://www.decisivetactics.com/products/serial/) and launched it. It immediately saw a connection called URT0, and whenever I inserted my serial device into the adaptor, Serial would see the NGT-1 device; whenever I pulled it out, Serial would recognize that it was gone. When the NGT-1 device was Opened in Serial, it would immediately start printing the incoming data. So the fact that nothing shows up in /dev does not seem to be due to some new security feature in the Pro. But it's just magic to me. I cannot see how to do what Serial is doing.